# How is [careers] both a tag and a synonym?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, tag-synonym-process

The meta-tag [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) is somehow both a synonym for [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) *and* a unique tag at the same time.

[image: Wait, is careers a tag or a synonym?]

- [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) is listed twice when selecting question tags
- Hovering over [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) displays info for [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs)
- List of tagged questions for [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) redirects to [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs)
- Both tags have separate wiki pages ([careers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/careers/info), [jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/jobs/info))
- Questions can use both tags simultaneously
- Number of tagged questions is displayed inconsistently

  - [Tag search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) displays [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) (753) and [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) (280)
  - [Tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/careers/info) displays combined total of 1,034 for both.

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens when an existing tag is set up as a synonym of another, but the two aren't merged.

Comment: Does that mean this is intended behavior?

Comment: I was about to write this and then remembers I've already written this on many occasions. [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204472) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152743) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248115)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes, although I can see how some parts of it are undesirable and/or confusing. (And IIRC new questions can't use both at the same time - [careers] should get remapped to [jobs].)

Comment: @animuson One of those questions should be chosen as a master so the other two can be closed as duplicates.

Comment: I'd like to continue this conversation in chat to avoid overcrowding the comments.

Comment: @Steven I agree this behavior is confusing and undesirable. I've been confused by it myself on numerous occasions, despite knowing how it works. (In fact, I could swear there have been previous discussions about this on Meta, but I can't find them, so maybe it was all MSE.) Ideally, it would be possible to easily undo merges and that would allow merging and synonymization to be simultaneous. But that would almost certainly require non-trivial changes to the backend and isn't likely to happen soon. So we really just need us mods to stay more on top of merging after a synonym is proven correct.

Comment: Is there any reason these tags shouldn't be merged?